# Apache Shiro - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, classnotfoundexception, shiro

I have hard time trying to use Apache Shiro in my web application (I'm using WildFly 10 and Eclipse IDE):

- I have downloaded binary distribution of Shiro (`shiro-all` from [here](http://shiro.apache.org/download.html#latestBinary))
- I have downloaded slf4j API from [here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)
- I have added both jars to classpath

However, when I try to use sample code, I get `ClassNotFoundException` with `AuthenticationToken` class. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: was you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is also highly recommended to use a dependency management tool (Maven, Gradle, Ivy, etc)

The `shiro-all` jar does NOT contain it's dependencies, so you would need to manually manage them.

Answer (score 0):

try to add **commons-logging.jar** in your classpath

if u can post some code like web.xml, shiro ini.

```
    <listener-class> class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```